# Java call static method of generic type

Tags: java, generics

I defined the following interface and class

```
public interface Storeable {
     public static String getId() {
        return "id";
    }
}

public class ABC implements Storeable{
    public static String getId() {
         return "id2";
     }
}
```

Further, I defined the following method where I get an error-message "The method getId() is undefined for the type T":

```
public static <T extends Storeable> T getItem(String id) {

    Class<T> classOfT;
    T.getId();
....
}
```

Why is this not working? Eclipse Quick-Fix simply creates a further static method in the interface

Comment: You cant use a static method in a generic context. The whole point of generics in the context of your example is to work with polymorphism, and static and polymorphism don't go together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access static methods by the type directly, so use `Storeable.getId()`

You cannot override a static method.